# Change glue in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, automated-tests, cucumber, build.gradle, cucumber-jvm

How can I change the `glue` path for a Gradle+Cucumber project?

This is the relevant part of a `build.gradle` file:

```
task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast{
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'gradle.cucumber', 'src/main/java/features']
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the `>gradle cucumber` from the command line, I get notified scenarios are not defined, because glue file is not in the `/main` folder, rather in `/main/java/stepmethods`.

How do I tell that to Gradle?

Comment: Is gradle.cucumber your package name?  --glue has to point to the package name of your step defs.

Comment: I know. That's what I want to change. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us say that you have a project named acmetesting.  Your project structure might look like:

```
acmetesting
  |
  +---src/main/java
       |
       +---com.acme.testing
            |
            +---steps
                 |
                 +---cucumberjvm302testbed
                      |
                      +---Cucumber302TestBedSteps.java
```

File Cucumber302TestBedSteps.java is your step definitions file and in the above configuration it would start off like:

```
 package com.acme.testing.steps.cucumberjvm302testbed;

 import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
 import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
 import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

 import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable;
 import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable.TableConverter;
 import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTableType;
 import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTableTypeRegistry;
 import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTableTypeRegistryTableConverter;
 import io.cucumber.datatable.TableEntryTransformer;

 import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Locale;
 import java.util.Map;
 ooo
```

So your args line would look like:

```
args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'com.acme.testing.steps', 'src/main/java/features']
```

**EDIT**
I removed cucumberjvm302testbed from the glue value to increase flexibility when other folders are added to steps.

Comment: That's it. I just needed to replace `gradle.cucumber` (that I copied from somewhere) with my actual step definition package.